# My self hosted website won't load on devices that are not connected to my network

Tags: nginx, portforwarding, self-hosting

I'm hosting my website on a raspberry pi using nginx, and i have opened port 80 on my router. But it still does not work outside of my network.

here is how i have configured my "default" file

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name wylie.club; 

        root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    
        location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

let me know if you need more resources from me, and thank you for helping out!

Comment: Does your ISP even allow port 80?

Comment: Yes, i have checked there blocked port list. 80 is not on there, i have spectrum.